# How trigger works for delete event in table? is atomicity is there when deleted record inserted into another table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created one after delete trigger for tracking deleted contact details.
I am importing CSV of 5000 records to 'contact' table.
     it is taking time of 4 minutes to import record in table
     i have imported csv 5 times means  5*4 = 20 min total to import 25k records.
I run query to delete all record from table and immediately shut down the system within 30 sec.
 I have expected that very less records must be inserted to another table 'deleted_contacts'. But surprised when i open the system and see the table deleted_contacts all 20 k records inserted in just 30 sec? How trigger insert is too fast in comparison to import CSV (20 min). What is reason behind that the trigger not fails in inserting all records even system shutdown immediately after DELETE ALL query from first table.

Comment: How are you uploading the CSV? I know using the import wizard in MySQL workbench is notoriously slow. `LOAD DATA INFILE` or the mysqlimport command would be similar in speed to the trigger deletion.

Comment: 5K rows should be inserted in about 1 second. Maybe 5 or 10 seconds - but not 4 minutues, as long as you don't insert long texts or blobs. So probably something is wrong with your import.